# Работа с sys.stdin

Tags: python

имеется вот такой код Python 3.

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
d = {}
for _ in data:
    actor = _.split(" - ")[0]
    action = _.split(" - ")[1]
    if actor in d:
        d[actor] = d[actor] + action
    else:
        d[actor] = action
for i in d:
    print(i, ":", end="")
    for ii in d[i]:
        print(" ", ii, end="")
    print()
```

Для ввода

```
aa - f
aa - s
bb - h
```

Вывод должен составлять

```
aa : f s
bb : h
```

А составляет он вместо этого

```
aa :  f
  s

bb :  h
```

Собственно, вопрос - почему? Я подозреваю, что где-то затесались лишние переходы на новую строку. Но что с ними делать?

Comment: Лишние переводы затесались в `data = ['aa - f\n', 'aa - s\n', 'bb - h']`.

Comment: Я что-то подобное подозревал. Как их оттуда убрать нормально?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лишние переводы затесались в `data`. Убрать можно с помощью метода строк `rstrip`.

***Пример:***

```py
data = ['aa - f\n', 'aa - s\n', 'bb - h']
data = list(map(str.rstrip, data))
print(data)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['aa - f', 'aa - s', 'bb - h']
```

---

Полный оптимизированный пример:

```py
data = ['aa - f\n', 'aa - s\n', 'bb - h']
data = list(map(str.rstrip, data))

d = {}
for s in data:
    actor, action = s.split(" - ")
    d[actor] = d.get(actor, '') + action

for x in d:
    print(x, ':', *d[x])
```

stdout:

```py
aa : f s
bb : h
```